# first time trying to install custom ROM on Samsung Galaxy Win (SHV-E500L)

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery

I have an old Samsung Galaxy Win (SHV-E500L) Korean version (Android 4.4)
 which I want to experiment on

I searched for custom ROMs for this model online but I haven't been able to find any

I am thinking of risking it and trying custom ROMs for The E300 phones (they are Galaxy S4 phones if I understand correctly)

One of the things I have read is that installing ClockworkMod is the first step to installing custom ROMs, and the [wikipedia for ClockworkMod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClockworkMod) says it

> ...replaces your Android device's stock recovery image. Using this
>   recovery image, various system-level operations can...

What are the risks associated with doing this? At the moment I can go into recovery mode on this phone by pressing home+volume up+ power button simultaneously. Does ClockworkMod replace this built in recovery mode? If it is, is there a way to get it back in case something goes wrong? I have used O[din to download stock firmware on this phone before](https://updato.com/how-to/how-to-install-an-official-samsung-stock-firmware-using-odin). Ideally, I want to be able to do it again multiple times and get it back to it's factory condition if something goes wrong.

If I manage to get ClockWorkMod on this phone, **will I still be able to get the phone back to it's default settings using Odin and stock ROM in case something goes wrong?** I do not have any special hardware for doing this so ideally any problems with the phone should be fixable through the standard USB port. The deice will not be used as a phone and only be used for it's camera and wifi.

Some details about the phone:

These aren't probably important details, but would still like to point them out. This phone previously had a problem where it would boot up to the telecom company logo but not go any further than that. The Download mode was still working so I managed to use Odin to download the stock ROM and the phone worked worked normally after that, but there were many background processes that would suddenly stop, giving an

```
Unfortunately, xxxx has stopped working
```

error box. This happened especially more frequently with Samsung Touch Wiz (which was fixed by installing Google's launcher) but started happening later on with other system apps as well. The problem happens more frequently if resource heavy programs such as games are run on the phone, but doesn't happen as much if it is just used for basic internet surfing and youtube from the browser. I am assuming there is some kind of problem with the phone's RAM related hardware, so I'm hoping that downloading some lite weight custom ROM without any bloatware will make the device run more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If You have stock rom,pc and odin then you can retain device to normal state as restored if you flash cwm or twrp you can still get your default recovery from Stock rom but don't flash wrong rom it might brick your device so be careful.